# Set of Homomorphisms as an $R-$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

$\require{AMScd}$
I'm reading *A first course of homogocial algebra* by *D.G. Northcott*, and I don't quite get the **Example 1** on page 25. Here's what it says:

## Example 1

> Let the module $A$ belongs to $\mathscr{C}_R$ (i.e the category of $R-$modules). Since $R$ is an $(R; R)-$bimodule. $\mbox{Hom}(R; A)$ is an $R-$module **of the same type as** $A$.

The bolded part is where I don't get it.

So, say I have $A$ as a **left** $R-$module, now I'll try to define the outer multiplication of $\mbox{Hom}(R; A)$, so to make it also a **left** $R-$module.

From this part on, I'll consider $f \in \mbox{Hom}(R; A)$; $r, \alpha \in R$.

### Trial 1

I define $(rf)(\alpha) = f(r\alpha)$. I don't think this should work, as:

$\begin{CD}
(r_1f)(r_2\alpha) @= r_2(r_1f)(\alpha) @= r_2f(r_1\alpha) @= \color{red}{r_2r_1}f(\alpha) \\ @| \\ f(r_1r_2\alpha) \\ @| \\ \color{red}{r_1r_2}f(\alpha)
\end{CD}$

### Trial 2

I define $(rf)(\alpha) = f(\alpha r)$. I don't think this should work, either:

$\begin{CD}
(r_1r_2f)(\alpha) @= (r_1(r_2f))(\alpha) @= r_1f(\alpha r_2) @= f(\alpha \color{red}{r_2 r_1}) \\ @| \\ f(\alpha \color{red}{r_1r_2})
\end{CD}$

---

I think I'm missing something really big here. I would be so glad if you guys can help me.

Thanks a lot in advance,

And have a good day,

Comment: In your Trial 1, your horizontal equality doesn't necessarily hold. You haven't proven that $r_1\cdot f$ is linear yet, but you are using that fact. If you define it as in my solutions, you can prove $R$ linearity. The thing in Trial 2 also has problems in the horizontal implication. $(r_1(r_2f))(\alpha)=(r_2f)(\alpha r_1)$ according to your definition. You can't perform the $r_2$ first, that would violate the order of operations.

Comment: I'm not trying to prove it, I try to disprove it instead, so I assume it to be linear, and try to conject something incorrect from it, it's sort of like Proof by Contradiction. :d

Comment: You can't draw a contradiction from it though, because *sometimes* it is true! For commutative rings, your definition works fine. The big question is whether or not the proposed definitions *produce* a module structure or not. The axioms would have to be verified to show that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be visually helpful to track the module side in the notation. To do that, I'll write $A_R$ to indicate a right $R$ module $A$, or $_RA$ to indicate a left $R$ module.

It will also help to consider bimodules over two different rings, since it will help keep us from confusing the module operations.

Suppose $_SB_R$ is a bimodule.

$H=Hom(B_R,A_R)$ has a natural *right* $S$ module structure via $(f\cdot s)(x):=f(sx)$.

Thus if $r$ is another element of $R$, $(f\cdot s)(xr)=f(sxr)=f(sx)r=(f\cdot s)(x)r$. You can see that the module actions are taking place on opposite sides of the ring, and so they don't need to "cross over" each other.

If $_TA_R$ is a bimodule, then $H$ has a natural *left* $T$ module structure given by

$(t\cdot f)(x):=tf(x)$. Again, $(t\cdot f)(xr)=tf(xr)=tf(x)r=(t\cdot f)(x)r$. The same thing has happened here that the $R$ module action and $T$ module action do not have to cross each other.

Both can happen at once: If $_TA_R$ and $_SB_R$ are bimodules, then $_TH_S$ is a bimodule, using both operations above (the compatibility $(th)s=t(hs)$ has to be checked.)

The problems with your definitions are that you are crowding the side of modules in the Hom and the new module action on one side, where they need to "cross over" each other in order to come out right. They really should be taking place on opposite sides of each other, as with these two definitions.

---

Let's work out the "left hand version" of this, which it looks like you'll need, since you're considering $H=Hom(_RR,_RA)$. The natural left module structure would arise from the *right* module structure of $R_R$. That is, $(r\cdot f)(x):=f(xr)$ would be a left $R$ linear map: $(r\cdot f)(r_1x)=f(r_1xr)=x_1(f(xr))=x_1(r\cdot f)(x)$

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused... So say $H = \mbox{Hom}(_SB_R; A_R)$ is a right $S-$ module via $(f \cdot s)(x) := f(sx)$. So if I expand $(f \cdot (s_1 s_2))(x) = f(\color{red}{s_1s_2} x)$, and $(f \cdot (s_1 s_2))(x) = ((f \cdot s_1) \cdot s_2)(x) = (f \cdot s_2)(s_1 x) = f(\color{red}{s_2s_1} x)$ I must be doing something wrong here, right? :(

Comment: Wait, I think I get it now. Thank you very much for your comment at the top. :* And thanks very much for your thorough explanation. :D

Comment: @user49685 Yes, $(f \cdot (s_1 s_2))(x) = ((f \cdot s_1) \cdot s_2)(x) = (f \cdot s_1)(s_2 x) = f(\color{red}{s_1s_2} x) $ is what it equals, but you did $(f \cdot s_2)(s_1 x)$, doing the operations in the wrong order. $s_2$ is the "outermost" first operation.

Comment: Yup, I get it. Thhhaaaaaannnkkkkssss so much... :*

Comment: @user49685 Cool! Thanks for asking such specific questions and showing your work. It really helped us pinpoint the problem :) If only all posters were that clear...