# Group action on set of maps - formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

It is given that $G:X$ and $G:Y$. 
Does this $[g\bullet f](x) := g\bullet f(g\bullet x)$ formula define group action $G:(Y^{X})$ I guess it doesn't, but I can't prove it as for now. And there must be some examples that show it.

On the contrary, this formula $\forall g\epsilon G;[g\bullet f](x):=g*f(g^{-1}*x),f\epsilon Y^{X}, x\epsilon X$ is correct, but I fail to comprehend it completely. I'm also curious how it (the correct one) was derived from the basic formula of group action on set. 
P.S. $G : X$ notation stands for group action on a set.

Comment: what does $G:S$ mean?

Comment: Action of group G on set S. I'd better add it to the post.

Comment: I am confused by this question. Where does $S$ come in? My problem is that I don't know what the formula is trying to convey. My guess is the following: $Y$ a set of functions $Y=\{f: X\rightarrow X^{\prime}\}$, and you are wanting to know if the formula you give defines the action of $G$ on $X^{\prime}$, given that $G$ acts on both $X$ and $Y$. Is this interpretation correct? (In your formula, I then guess that $g\in G$, $f\in Y$ and $x\in X$. Yes?)

Comment: what is $S$ versus $X$ or $Y$?

Comment: @user1729, I'm sorry, that was a typo. It is X, not S.

Comment: @user1729, $Y^{X}$ is a set of all maps from X to Y. I don't think the complement of the set X has anything to do with it. Your assumptions about g and x are correct.

Comment: @Dan By $X^{\prime}$ I just meant some set denoted by $x^{\prime}$, not the complement. Your comment had cleared it up though.

Answer (score 2):

So $G$ acts on sets $X$ and $Y$ (on the left). On the set $Y^X$ of all maps $X \to Y$ we try to define an action of $G$. Of course $(gf)(x):=g f(gx)$ doesn't work since you can immediately check that this doesn't satisfy $(gh)f = g(hf)$. But when you define $(gf)(x):=g f(g^{-1} x)$, then we have $1f=f$ (clear) and $(gh)f=g(hf)$ , since for all $x \in X$ we have
$$g(h(f))(x)=g h(f)(g^{-1}x) = g (h f(h^{-1} g^{-1} x))=gh f((gh)^{-1} x) =((gh)f)(x)$$
This action might seem strange at first sight, because the inverse is involved. But it has the nice property that it is, in fact, an action, and notice that the fixed points (i.e. those functions $f$ with $gf=f$ for all $g \in G$) are exactly the $G$-equivariant maps $X \to Y$. In symbols, we have $\hom(X,Y)^G = \hom_G(X,Y)$. This is quite useful.

Also notice the following more general construction: Let $G$ act on $X$ on the *right* and let $H$ act on $Y$ on the *left*. Then $Y^X$ has an action from $G \times H$ on the *left*, defined by $((g,h)f)(x):=h f(xg)$. By taking inverses, any right action can be turned into a left action, and vice versa. But this inverse-free construction works in great generality (closed symmetric monoidal categories where $G,H$ are replaced by arbitrary monoid objects), a special case being [modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393797/) over rings. Notice that the right action of $G$ on $X$ becomes a left action of $G$ on $Y^X$ because $X \mapsto Y^X$ is a contravariant functor.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed and clear answer! Group theory is truly a beautiful thing. I still wonder what are geometrical examples of that action, I have something in my mind but I'm not sure... Could you please give some? 
Besides, what source would you recommend for studying this subject? The books I have lack formulae for group actions on sets of maps at all, which is quite disappointing.